# Polynomial equation retrieval

Tags: python, regression, polynomial-math

There is a dataset with x and y, and I need to know the equation for y ( how it was modeled).So I use coeficents and power from a model with 99% score:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
Xtrain_tr = poly.fit_transform(Xtrain)
Xtest_tr = poly.fit_transform(Xtest)
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(Xtrain_tr, ytrain)
poly=poly.powers_
coef=model.coef_
coef
out:    array([  0.        ,   4.25571706,   0.59691212,  20.28394618,
           162.97671755])

    poly
 out:   array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

And here I am trying to mimic y value for firs row in dataset:

```
temp=0
final=0
i=0

for i in range(4):
    temp=(X_train[:1]**poly[i])*coef[i]
    temp=temp.values.sum()

    final=final+temp
    temp=0
    i=i+1
```

The result is not satisfying, please suggest what I can improve here.
Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is quite vague. Please explain what you mean by "The result is not satisfying" and the kind of improvement you want. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After creating a polynomial model, you wish to reproduce the modeling result for the first row of data but the result is not the same. Is this correct?

Comment: yes,that's right

Comment: I see that you have already posted the fitted coefficient values, would you also please post the first row data so we can also make the same test that you did?

Comment: Yes, sure. 0 \ 17.967976\ -0.195198  \ -2 \    1     .I added zero value in the first column, cause there are 5 coefficients

Comment: and y =  23.244252 for this row

Comment: There can be different reasons for the problem that you observe. Starting with `LinearRegression` failing to do a good fit due to the difference in scale between different features (assuming the values that you quoted for the first example are representative) and ending with your linear model with 1-st order polinomial features not being to describe the data that you have at hand. Did you try to go beyond `PolynomialFeatures(1)`?